# using form variables for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch a result from a mysql table using two form variables namely $sessionID and $semesterID. I used the following code and it seems to have an error in the sql syntax

```
<?php
...
mysql_select_db($database_connChePortal, $connChePortal);
$query_rsRegcourses =sprintf("SELECT * FROM VW_reg vwr WHERE vwr.sessionID=%s AND vwr.semesterID=%s",$sessionID,$semesterID);
$rsRegcourses = mysql_query($query_rsRegcourses, $connChePortal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsRegcourses = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegcourses);
$totalRows_rsRegcourses = mysql_num_rows($rsRegcourses);
print_r($query_rsRegcourses); die;

...
?>
```

I tried running the query and I have the following error report

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND vwr.semesterID=' at line 1
```

thanks

Comment: In addition to the missing single quotes as others have noted, you're also not escaping that data before putting it into the db. You should be using mysql_real_escape_string (or something better like PDO, mysqli, or an ORM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should surround your variable with single quotes `''` please change as follow

```
"SELECT * FROM VW_reg vwr WHERE vwr.sessionID='%s' AND vwr.semesterID='%s'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the %s in single quotes like this

```
"SELECT * FROM VW_reg vwr WHERE vwr.sessionID='%s' AND vwr.semesterID='%s'",$sessionID,$semesterID);
```

Comment: I thought %s was used here for string, so the answer was in that context. Also the error looks like because of that. I never said you should always use like this

Comment: @chandresh_cool ... Thanks mehn it really worked..will keep that in mind when using string or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a variable into query, **you have to properly format it**.
Two other answers contains improper formatting - so, you shouldn't follow them.

To make formatting more handy, you have to encapsulate `sprintf()` into function like this:

```
function paraQuery()
{
    $args  = func_get_args();
    $query = array_shift($args);
    $query = str_replace("%s","'%s'",$query); 

    foreach ($args as $key => $val)
    {
        $args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    }

    $query  = vsprintf($query, $args);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        throw new Exception(mysql_error()." [$query]");
    }
    return $result;
}
```

which would apply proper formatting and also will handle errors

Also note that your way of counting records is extremely inefficient and may cause server to hang. You have to query the only data you need. So, if you need only count - request the count only

so, the code would be

```
mysql_select_db($database_connChePortal, $connChePortal);
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM VW_reg vwr WHERE vwr.sessionID=%s AND vwr.semesterID=%s";
$res = paraQuery($sql,$sessionID,$semesterID);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
print_r($row[0]); die;
```

it will make your query properly formatted and thus invulnerable to SQL injection

also, it seems that `$semesterID` is not set which may cause some problem too